# What kind of method to storage data on Android learn application

Tags: android, html, json, xml, display

I am going to write an android application that allow to learn language programming. An example, it's PHP:
My application will has two functions:

- Function A: Learn theory, like that: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/
- Function B: Interview question, like that: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_interview_questions.htm

With Function A, I create html pages for each articles, store html page on project, then display it via webview, like that:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + value);
```

*Note: value is html file that stored on asset folder.*

With Function B, there are so many questions and answers. It's too long to create html file. I have thinked about XML or JSON format. Does it appropriate to do that? Have you another better solution ?

p/s: sorry about tags, I can not make fully tag with my reputation.

Comment: Why is it too long to create an HTML file? Does an HTML file has a limit?

Comment: @user3793589: In the case I have 100 questions and answers, is it long time to create html file? And there are some unknow memory problems that i will get.

Comment: So basically you are creating a website, and you display that in an app. This will probably not look too good, or really look like an Android app ! My advice would be to forget about HTML, think about real design guidelines for your lessons (sections, headers, titles...), then create your own format to store this structured content (I'd go with sqlite or Json, compressed). If you do things right, look and feel will be better !

Comment: Looks like all you need is an ExpandableListView. You are trying to write an Android app, not a webapp

Comment: @kidsoul, where are those questions stored currently ?

Comment: @personne3000: thank for you advance. you made me reframe.

Comment: @cricket_007: ExpandableListView is just GUI, is not the solution for saving data.

Comment: @user3793589: that's my question, sir

Comment: @kidsoul, Well... Since, you don't know where the questions are, if it is a long time creating the HTML file, it will take you the exact same long time to insert them in a database (even local database like sqlite) you will create yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Based on:
[Home » Android JSON Parsing – Retrieve From MySQL Database
Android JSON Parsing](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-mysql-database/)
from April 20, 2015 by Belal Khan

You can store your data in a MySQL database and load it using PHP JSON.
For example, the PHP file that encodes JSON is:

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','user');
define('PASS','pass');
define('DB','dbname');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$sql = "select * from questions";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array(); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,
        array('id'=>$row[0],
              'question'=>$row[1],
              'answer'=>$row[2]
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and the Java code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String myJSON;

private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
private static final String TAG_ANSWER ="answer";

JSONArray peoples = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> QuestionList;

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    QuestionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    getData();
}


protected void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        results = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<results.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String question = c.getString(TAG_QUESTION);
            String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSWER);

            HashMap<String,String> questions = new HashMap<String,String>();

            questions.put(TAG_ID,id);
            questions.put(TAG_QUESTION,question);
            questions.put(TAG_ANSWER,answer);

            QuestionList.add(questions);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_QUESTION,TAG_ANSWER},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.question, R.id.answer}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/get-data.php");

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            }
            finally {
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}
```

You have to add a list view in your layout 
and don't forget to add internet permission in the manifest.

Comment: @king-il: Thank for you detail answer. But I only want to make a local application, sir. I saw your reference tutorial website. It just use JSON format to load data from server to client, doesn't it? Is it good if I make JSON file, then load to application ?

Comment: @king-il: another question, what about Google server ?

Comment: @kidsoul If you want to make a local application you can use SQLite

Answer (score 1):

If you are making an android app that has internet access, you could create a database that store all of the questions and answers. So every time the user goes to view the questions, it sends a request to your web server and the web server responses by sending the data from the database.

If you only want to make an app using local database, you can implement the Android SQLite database. Here is the Android documentation on SQLite Database: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

However, regarding to your question of how long it takes to create a html file or database, it always takes you a while to put all of that data into database unless you already have all of the data in some format that can be converted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: about local db, is JSON better ?

Comment: SQLite database is usually used for storing static data locally. JSON is a format not a type of database and it is usually used for transferring data between a web server and client. You can store everything into a file or files in JSON format using internal storage. However, SQLite is the usual choice when doing local storage